# Reset Cisco 1130 AP Enable Password via Console

Tags: cisco

I picked up some Cisco AG 1130 AP's off ebay and have been trying to reset the enable passwords via console. I followed the instructions on Cisco's website:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/wireless/aironet-1130-ag-series/products-password-recoveries-list.html

Basically, when you console in and reboot the device, you are supposed to hit ESC while the device begins to inflate the image, but when I do that in OSX's Terminal, hitting ESC seems to do absolutely nothing.

Has anyone ran into this specific issue; trying to stop the image inflation while consoled in with Terminal. I also tried using PuTTy on Windows, but I still cant interrupt the image inflation.

Comment: Try sending a <break> instead of escape.

Comment: Try with `Ctrl + Break ` or hiting ESC several times during its booting process.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you bought this AP (not a new one), I would suggest you reset it to the default configuration and reload the AP image using MODE button ([Link here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/1130/installation/guide/1130-TD-Book-Wrapper/113h_c3.html#wp1036746)):

> **Resetting to the Default Configuration**
>
> If you forget the password
> that allows you to configure the access point, you may need to
> completely reset the configuration. You can use the MODE button on the
> access point or the web-browser interface.
>
> Note: The following steps reset all configuration settings to factory
> defaults, including passwords, WEP keys, the IP address, and the SSID.
>
> **Using the MODE Button**
>
> Follow these steps to delete the current configuration and return all access point settings to the factory defaults using the MODE button:
>
> **Step 1:** Open the access point cover
>
> **Step 2:** Disconnect power (the power jack for
> external power or the Ethernet cable for in-line power) from the
> access point.
>
> **Step 3:** Press and hold the **MODE** button while you
> reconnect power to the access point.
>
> **Step 4:** Hold the **MODE** button
> until the Ethernet LED turns an amber color (approximately 2 to 3
> seconds), and release the button.
>
> **Step 5:** After the access point
> reboots, you must reconfigure the access point by using the Web
> browser interface, the Telnet interface, or Cisco IOS commands.
>
> Note The access point is configured with the factory default values
> including the IP address (set to receive an IP address using DHCP).

Comment: As the link may goes down, please copy relevant information into your answer (keeping the link for reference and proper attribution)

Comment: @JFL Thanks for your feedback. I updated it accordingly.